# Can some explain what is sc._jvm and sc._jsc in spark? For what purpose these 2 are used in spark?

Tags: java, apache-spark, jvm, bigdata

I work in spark with Python, What does the below code do?

```
jvm = sc._jvm
jsc = sc._jsc
fs = jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(jsc.hadoopConfiguration())
if fs.exists(jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(loc+"_SUCCESS")):
    df=spark.read.parquet(loc)
    df.write.mode("overwrite").parquet(hdfs_bkp_loc)
else:
```

Comment: This was the exact lines that I am looking for :) Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Since Spark is written in Scala, which is a JVM based language. PySpark has a JVM running behind the scenes to actually run the spark code.
`sc._jvm` is the gateway into said JVM and `sc._jsc` is the Java Spark Context which is a proxy into the SparkContext in that JVM.

The snippet you posted basically calls some Java functions to check is some path exists and then read some data from there to be written into another location.

Using these `_jsc` members is discouraged and quite rare that you would need them.

Comment: Thank you @LiorRegev for your response. Is there any blog or other material to understand these 2 parameters in detail?

Comment: Not that I know of it, but since it's just the representation of a JVM object you could refer to the JavaDoc/ScalaDoc for Spark to get more info. But most of everything can be achieved without accessing them

Comment: For internal information on Spark, I would refer to: https://books.japila.pl/apache-spark-internals/overview/

Comment: Thank you Lior!!!